# concatenate dynamic value in nested sql statement java

Tags: java, sql

I tried finding information on it,but there doesn't seem to be examples on it.
I have this line:

```
long userID = user.getId();
String query = "select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where userclient.userid = " +
            "(select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = "+userID+")";
```

but Eclipse reads the "userID" as a string,and not as a variable.How can I make Eclipse read "userID" as a variable?

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse? What do you mean by _"Eclipse reads the "userID" as a string?"_ Where/how? I don't see a "read" happening anywhere. In fact, all you're doing is assigning 2 variables.

Comment: What I meant was I want the variable userID to be passed as a dynamic value in the where clause (in the last part of the SQL statement),not as part of a string in that SQL statement.But it seems that I had not concatenate the statement properly.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and input parameters for the placeholder `?`.

Example usage (from JavaDocs):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY = ? WHERE ID = ?");
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, 153833.00)
stmt.setInt(2, 110592)
```

Applying that example to your case, you would get something like:

```
// prepare connection "conn" earlier
long userID = user.getId();
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where userclient.userid = (select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = ?)");
stmt.setLong(1, userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this::

```
long userID = user.getId();
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where userclient.userid =");
queryBuilder.append("(select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = ?)");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString());
stmt.setInt(1, userId);
```